# Is an unused function still present in the executable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a function call to .h and .cpp files, which is used to push data to a display so I can see what is going on while i am testing the program.
I commented out the function call referring to .h and .cpp files so it does not run in the final version of the program.

Since i have the function commented out along with the namespace commented out, when i compile the program will VS 2013 compiler ignore the commented out code along with the .h and .cpp and not put it in the compiled file/executable, or should i completely remove the function calls and namespace reference along with referring .cpp and .h files from the project before compiling?

This is just about the final size of the project and I do not want to have things in it that will not be used.
I only use that big peice code for testing.

Comment: If you commented it out, it will not be in your compiled files.

Comment: uh...what exactly is your question?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Please restate it.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
// just a comment
```

is identical to this code:

from the compiler's point of view.

Comment: So what your saying is that it won't take up or make any unnecessary space in the final .exe which I will be uploading to a embedded system if I leave the files in the project.

Comment: Well, honestly, your question is quite unclear. Perhaps you want to know whether a defined function is present in the resulting executable even if it is not called, don't you?

Comment: I really want to know if the .h and .cpp files which are referred by the function will also be compiled if the function is commented out.

Comment: Like this answer says commented out code is not compiled/included. It's all just left behind and won't be in your output.

Comment: what about the linked .h and .cpp files the comented out code refers too. they are still in the project and i hope they will not be included as well??

Comment: It depends on compiler optimizations. However, the debug stuff is usually handled explicitly using dedicated macros. Both function call `#ifdef _DEBUG` / `debug_func();` / `#endif` and function definition `#ifdef _DEBUG` / `void debug_func() { ... }` / `#endif` are kept in debug build only. No need to comment anything, just the build mode is switched.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to figure this out myself since my question must have been to hard to comprehend or respond to.

I compiled the program with everything in, meaning nothing was commented out. I then commented out the function call but left in the referring .cpp and .h files in the project and compiled it again. finally I completely removed/deleted the function calls and the referring `.cpp` and `.h` files and compiled it a third time.
Results were after 3 hours were; the last two .exe files that were compiled were 1.5 Mb smaller then the first whole compiled program. Meaning/hoping/thinking that just commenting out the function call meant that since there was no reference anymore to the `.h` and `.cpp` files they did not get compiled.

Comment: Perhaps a much simpler question "Is unused function still present in the executable?" wouldn't result in downvotes and would produce higher number of useful answers. In other words: If a single person doesn't understand your question, perhaps he/she is stupid. If nobody understands your question...

Comment: Sure I could have edited the question if someone would have given me the chance instead of just posting negative votes. I thought we are here to help and not slam!